# $M\cong_{R\operatorname{-Mod}}N$ if and only if $M\cong_{\operatorname{Ab}}N$ (Warning: This statement is FALSE!)

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

I was rather surprised by the fact that two modules are isomorphic if and only if their abelian group structures are isomorphic. I might just sketch the proof here.

Given a ring homomorhpism $R\xrightarrow{f}S$, we have the *restriction of scalors* functor $S\operatorname{-Mod}\xrightarrow{f_*}R\operatorname{-Mod}$ defined in the most natural way. That is, each $S$-module $N$ is turned into an $R$-module by the action \begin{equation}
r\cdot n\colon = f(r)n.
\end{equation}

One amazing fact is that $f_*$ is faithfully exact, and in particular $M\cong_{S\operatorname{-Mod}}N$ if and only if $f_*(M)\cong_{R\operatorname{-Mod}}f_*(N)$.

Now $\mathbb{Z}$ is initial in $\operatorname{Ring}$, so we have \begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{f}R
\end{equation} for any $R$. Then the above says \begin{equation}
M\cong_{\mathbb{Z}\operatorname{-Mod}}N
\end{equation} if and only if \begin{equation}
M\cong_{R\operatorname{-Mod}}N.
\end{equation}  So that two modules are isomorphic if and only if their underlying abelian group structures are isomorphic since $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are exactly abelian groups.

> But this proof is rather high-brow, and left me still wondering why this could be true. I wonder whether there is a more down-to-earth proof.

Thanks!

**Edit:** The above proof is **WRONG**. The faithful exactness of $f_*$ only says \begin{equation}M\xrightarrow{\phi} N\end{equation} is an $R$-module isomorphism if and only if \begin{equation}
M\xrightarrow{f_*(\phi)}N
\end{equation} is a group isomorphism. But there are possible isomorphisms between $M$ and $N$ that are not of the form $f_*(\phi)$. If this happens (as in the example given by Chris Eagle) then the two groups are isomorphic but the modules are not.

Comment: Where did you get that proof from? (As noted in the answer, the result is not true).

Comment: What is true is that an $R$-module homomorphism is an $R$-module isomorphism if and only if it is a bijection, i.e. that the forgetful functor $R\textbf{-Mod} \to \textbf{Set}$ is conservative (and hence the forgetful functor $R\textbf{-Mod} \to \textbf{Ab}$ and restriction of scalars functor etc.).  But that is a fact of undergraduate algebra.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I learnt this from [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf), where it appears as exercise 3.6 of chapter VIII, although the original statement says *a sequence of $R$-modules is exact if and only if the corresponding sequence of abelian groups is exact*. But we can take the exact sequence to be $0\to M\to N\to 0$, or can we?

Comment: @ZhenLin Silly me! Thanks so much!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks! I got it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is false. $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{R}$ are isomorphic as abelian groups, but not as $\Bbb{R}$-modules.